# Why is my android alarm manager firing instantly?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-appwidget, android-pendingintent

I am following sample code for sending an update notification every 10'seconds.  The code follows and it is in an `UpdateService` for an `AppWidgetProvider`. If I put a `Thread.sleep(10*1000);` I can see the expected behavior of my servicing loop. I obviously have something fundamentally wrong that is triggering immediately. It is supposed to be a `PendingIntent` of an alarm that will broadcast update to my listener.

```
long nextUpdate = 10*1000;
Log.d(TAG, "Requesting next update in " + nextUpdate + " msec." );

Intent updateIntent = new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE_ALL);
updateIntent.setClass(this, UpdateService.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, updateIntent, 0);

// Schedule alarm, and force the device awake for this update
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 
    nextUpdate, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

AlarmManager.setRepeating is defined as `public void setRepeating (int type, long triggerAtTime, long interval, PendingIntent operation)` The 2nd argument is when it should be first called. You're telling it to start at `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`, which is now.

Comment: Thanks to both +1 from me for the quick and accurate answer.  On to the next problem.  Quite ironically, I tried to put a second comment too soon (<15 seconds), so I get a timer-pop notification from SO. :))

Comment: im doing it like this `amAlarm1.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 120000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarm1Pending); still pending intent is firing instantly??`

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: You should really post a new question. But to answer your question anyway, you're passing `120000` to triggerAtTime, which corresponds to `Fri, 02 Jan 1970 09:20:00 GMT`

Comment: @Falmarri thanks for this new information (any way 120000 is just for testing) , but the problem was **InexactRepeating**, which doesn't gurantee to run on user define trigger, i used `setRepeating` and it work like a charm it supposed to be :)

Comment: I'm not even using setRepeating or setInexactRepeating and my alarm is still firing instantly.

Answer (score 16):

You are telling [`setRepeating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) that you want the first alarm to go off immediately (`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`). If you want the first alarm to go off some other time, add an offset (`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+nextUpdate`).

Comment: Thanks to both +1 from me for the quick and accurate answer.  On to the next problem.

Comment: You can use System.currentTimeMillis() +nextUpdate.

Comment: @Suresh: The code in the question is using `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME`. For that, you need to use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` as the time base. If you want to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` as the time base, you need to use `AlarmManager.RTC` as the alarm type.

Answer (score 6):

If you are creating PendingIntent of an alarm for past time it will be fired immediately. Example - Schedule alarm for today 8AM but executing code around 11AM will fire immediately.

Solution:

```
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

long delay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), delay,pendingIntent);`
```

This will fire the event on next day at specified time (i.e 8AM);