# set the time in Alarm manager Android - alarm fired instantly

Tags: android, time, calendar, alarm, alarmmanager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my android alarm manager firing instantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358984/why-is-my-android-alarm-manager-firing-instantly)

I have this code which will call alarm notification

```
public static  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
Intent intent = new Intent(this,  OnetimeAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent,0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() , pendingIntent); 
Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but the alarm is fired instantly , it dosent wait after the given hour and minutes ?
should I add anything to to the manifest file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the current time to set the alarm. So it fires instantly.

Check the API. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29

There you pass the time when the alarm goes of as the second parameter. In your case this is the actual time. So you should add the amount of time you want to wait to the time your passing in the method right now.

Comment: I want it to be fired after "hour" and "min" as you can see cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, min);  // hour will be for example 5 and min will be 30 , but its not working too!

Comment: then show the code where you set the hour and min variable